# Can't figure out why MYSQL query is so slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following from my EXPLAIN query. I don't know how I can use this to improve my query performance. My query is as follows:

```
SELECT
   `b`.`business_name` AS `Name`,
   `b`.`address` AS `Address`,
   `b`.`city` AS `City`,
   `b`.`phone_number` AS `Phone`,
   `b`.`state` AS `Prov`,
   `i`.`date` AS `Last_Observed`,
   group_concat(`v`.`notes` separator ', ') AS `Notes`,
   `v`.`critical` AS `Criticality`,
   `i`.`type` AS `Inspection_Type`,
   `i`.`rating` AS `Rating`
FROM (`fs_v1_violation_table` `v`
LEFT JOIN (`fs_v1_inspection_table` `i`
LEFT JOIN `fs_v1_business_table` `b` ON((`b`.`id` = `i`.`business_id`))) 
ON((`i`.`id` = `v`.`inspection_id`)))
WHERE `v`.`type` = 'Cleanliness' AND (
   b.city = 'North Vancouver'
   OR b.city = 'Vancouver'
   OR b.city = 'White Rock'
   OR b.city = 'West Vancouver'
   OR b.city = 'Burnaby'
   OR b.city = 'Langley'
   OR b.city = 'Maple Ridge'
   OR b.city = 'Delta' 
   OR b.city = 'Surrey')
GROUP BY `i`.`id`
ORDER BY `i`.`date` desc;
```

Any ideas on where I might look to improve performance? Query takes ~3 minutes.

[image: Explain Query]

Comment: try EXPLAIN: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Comment: use `explain` method to check.

Comment: try to create index on b.city

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. Will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), and return unpredictable data with older versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your query seems to be against the sql standard because the select list contains fields that are not in the group by list, nor are functionally dependent on the fields in the group by list, nor are aggregated using an aggregate function such as `min()` or `sum()`. Unfortunately, MySQL allows such queries to be run under certain sql mode settings. Luckily, this setting is now off by default.

Use `IN (...)` instead of a series of ORs and make sure you have a multi column index on `fs_v1_business_table` table's `id, city` fields to speed up the query. You may also consider creating a multi-column index on `fs_v1_inspection_table` table's `business_id, id, date` fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reduce the row amount as soon as posible.

Create index from 'b.city' column.

Example SQL.

```
SELECT
   `b`.`business_name` AS `Name`,
   `b`.`address` AS `Address`,
   `b`.`city` AS `City`,
   `b`.`phone_number` AS `Phone`,
   `b`.`state` AS `Prov`,
   `i`.`date` AS `Last_Observed`,
   group_concat(`v`.`notes` separator ', ') AS `Notes`,
   `v`.`critical` AS `Criticality`,
   `i`.`type` AS `Inspection_Type`,
   `i`.`rating` AS `Rating`
FROM `fs_v1_violation_table` AS `v`
LEFT JOIN `fs_v1_inspection_table` AS `i` ON `i`.`id` = `v`.`inspection_id`
LEFT JOIN `fs_v1_business_table` AS `b` ON `b`.`id` = `i`.`business_id` AND b.city IN ('North Vancouver', 'Vancouver', 'White Rock', 'West Vancouver', 'Burnaby', 'Langley', 'Maple Ridge', 'Delta', 'Surrey')
WHERE `v`.`type` = 'Cleanliness'
GROUP BY `i`.`id`
ORDER BY `i`.`date` desc;
```